# Android starting existing app instance from Widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, instance, launchmode

I have an app that contains several activities...so lets say user is navigating activity stack A->B->C. Then presses the HOME button. Now when the user clicks on the Widget, I just want bring my app's existing/current instance to the foreground. I do NOT want a new instance of the app. I want activity C to get back to foreground.

I tried launchMode to `"singleTask" | "singleInstance"` but that does NOT solve my desired requirement since it clears the current instance and creates a new one with activity A.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure out a solution. I set the specialized launch mode....

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Every time the user clicks on the widget or the app icon again, the default activity A is started. To open the app up where it last was, inside the `onCreate()` method in your `MainActivity` class just check `isTaskRoot()`. If false, call `finish()` and the activity A (MainActivity) will not appear and the app will open up to where it was in activity B.

Answer (score 2):

Using a "`singleInstance`" is not such a good idea (for many reasons).
Here is a better way - from your widget intent handler:

```
Intent yourActivity = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
yourActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(yourActivity);
```

You don't need to add `CLEAR_TOP` to recall activity C, but you need it if you want to bring A or B.

I am only posting because between some 10+ similar posts nobody actually pointed the correct way of doing it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP - last paragraph.

Comment: I had this problem when trying to launch an activity from widget (service), this solved it!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your intent

```
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
```